# multiple models to one manytomanyfield table

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I have two apps `Levels, Classes` with Many To Many Relationships, `Levels` can have many `Classes`, and `Classes` can have many `Levels`.

I want `classes` and `levels` use the same table.

How can I do that?

I tried:

**levels/models.py**

```py
class Level(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(ChildClass, related_name='childclass', blank=True,db_table='level_class', primary_key=False)
```

**child_class/models.py**

```py
class ChildClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    levels = models.ManyToManyField('level.Level', related_name='childclass',db_table='level_class')
```

**Returns *(Error)***

> child_class.ChildClass.levels: (fields.E340) The field's intermediary table 'level_class' clashes with the table name of 'level.Level.classes'.
> level.Level.classes: (fields.E340) The field's intermediary table 'level_class' clashes with the table name of 'child_class.ChildClass.levels'.

Comment: The exception tells you that you're trying to use the same table for two different relationships. It looks like you're declaring the same m2m relationship on both classes - you don't need to do that, declaring it on one of them is sufficient. The other will have access to the relation through an automatically created reverse manager. You might want to refresh on the `ManyToManyField` documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Comment: I know, i want classes and levels to use the same table @PeterDeGlopper

Comment: You can't have two relations share the same table. But you don't _need_ to in order to allow classes to have many levels and levels to have many classes, that's what many-to-many means.

Comment: I just did it, you can create one more model and use `through` to the 3rd model we created

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have defined two ManyToManyField relationships in two different models (Level and ChildClass), and you are trying to use the same intermediary table 'level_class' for both relationships.

In a many-to-many relationship, you should only define the relationship on one side, and the other side can access it via the related_name attribute.

In your case, you can remove the ManyToManyField from the ChildClass model, and only keep it in the Level model.

Try this:

```py
#levels/models.py

from django.db import models
from child_class.models import ChildClass

class Level(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(ChildClass, related_name='levels', blank=True)
```

```py
#child_class/models.py
from django.db import models

class ChildClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
According to the Django documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/, under many to many relationship you can create an intermediary model to Foreign key both the Level and Class models to hold the fields that are common and govern both the models. Also the many to many relationship can only be defined on one model not both and it is recommended you put the relationship on a model that brings sense.

class Level(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128


class ChildClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Level, through="Intermediate")


class Intermediate(models.Model):
    Level= models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ChildClass= models.ForeignKey(ChildClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: This is valid but you only need the intermediate model if you want extra fields on the `through` model, like a "date added" value. If you just have the two FKs you only need to declare the `ManyToManyField`.